# kubuntu / Windows xp partition- want to upgrade to windows 7 but keep kbuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, kubuntu, windows-xp, partitioning

I have dual boot: Windows XP and Kubuntu. I want to upgrade to windows 7 but naturally want to keep Kubuntu. If i do a clean installation of windows 7 will that delete the Kubuntu partitions on my HD and delete os and leave  me only with windows7?

Does anyone know?
Do you have any special recommendation or just proceed normally with the installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work just fine if you install Windows 7 over the XP install, just make sure to select the correct hard drive during installation.  NOTE:  You will need to run a grub reparation tool like boot-repair.

EDIT:  Here's the specific command you need to run to fix the bootloader:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: That's to make sure to have the 2 option when starting the computer right? Kubuntu and Win7? Would Gparted work for that?

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes.

Comment: But in the Windows 7 install there should be an option that writes over Windows XP only, and you would be able to tell by looking at the hard disks in the window where you select one.

Answer (score 0):

You may just delete the Windows XP partition from the Windows 7 installer so it makes `System Reserved`. Then install Windows 7 in the freed space. After that you may use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) CD to fix GRUB or [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to add Ubuntu to the Windows bootloader.